# If $X_1,X_2,X$ are iid random variables with $X_1+X_2$ has the distribution of $aX$, find all characteristic functions of $X$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, fourier-analysis, characteristic-functions

If $X_1,X_2,X$ are iid random variables with $X_1+X_2$ have the same distribution as $aX$ for some real $a$, what are the possible characteristic functions of $X$?

Let $\varphi_X(t)$ be characteristic function of $X$. Then $$\varphi_X^2(t)=\varphi_{X_1+X_2}(t)=\varphi_{aX}(t)=\varphi_X(at).$$

By iterating the above functional equation we get $$\varphi_X^{2n}(t)=\varphi_X(a^nt)$$
for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I have no idea how to approach the problem form here. Any ideas?

Comment: You should note that $a$ must be equal to $\pm\sqrt{2}$ (unless $X$ is almost surely constant, and then $\phi_X (t)=e^{i\xi t}$ for some $\xi$): because $X_1,X_2$ are independent (hence uncorrelated), we have:
$$
Var(X)+Var(X)=Var(X_1)+Var(X_2)=Var(X_1+X_2)=Var(aX)=a^2 Var(X)
$$

Also, this implies (by now taking expectancies) that $\mathbb{E}X=0$

Comment: @MielSharf It is not necessarily true that $\mathrm{Var}\, X <\infty$.

Comment: Yeah, $a=2$ is classics.